# Oracle Forms troubleshooting: 10g to 12c conversion

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c, oracleforms

I am running out of options and I hope somebody can help/advise.

We are doing Forms upgrade from **10.1.2.0.2** to **12.2.1.2.0**.

We are going "fresh install, convert forms and deploy to new server" route.
Oracle forms server 12.2.1.2.0 appears OK since I can successfully run anything from default section from **`formsweb.cfg`** (message "Installed successfully").

One of developers converted forms, however when I try to run that section form appears loading (JAVA security etc) but then screen (internet explorer) goes blank (white).

Problem is I cannot see any single error anywhere so I can check where it fails. Nothing from `$DOMAIN_HOME/servers/WLS_FORMS/`logs shows any error sign and I enabled `serverURL=/forms/lservlet/debug` (debug messages in **`formsapp-diagnostic.log`**).

I even run form directly  with `&record=forms&tracegroup=0-199`, got output files in `$DOMAIN_HOME/system_components/FORMS/forms1/trace` then tried to convert to meaningfull **.txt**. with:

```
java oracle.forms.diagnostics.Xlate datafile=forms_27233.trc outputfile=myfile.txt outputclass=WriteOutTEXT
```

but I am getting next error (not sure how to fix this):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at oracle.forms.diagnostics.FormsInfo.interpret(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.diagnostics.FormsInfo.process(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.diagnostics.ReadDataFile.readEvent(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.diagnostics.Xlate.process(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.diagnostics.Xlate.main(Unknown Source)
```

How can I enable server to get some feedback when forms is loaded?

**Details:**

Oracle Forms Server 12.2.1.2.0 on Oracle Linux Server release 7.3 (4.1.12-94.3.6.el7uek.x86_64)

Previously, Forms were running on Windows Server 2003R2 and conversion was done on Windows 7.

Could this be issue?

Comment: do you have any "list item" with "List Type" of "Combo Box", in that spesific form?

Comment: There is no Combo Box in form.